# Link disappears after use of :after property in css

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am currently trying to speed up the load time of a website. When I took on this project there were rollover images that would brighten up the images to slightly signify you are over a 'category'. I knew you could do this in css without having to use two of the exact same images (with the second just a little brighter.) I used the :after property to add a white background with a higher z-index with a slight opacity to mimic this idea.
    In the previous home page these 'category images' were clickable but after implementing the :after pseudo element the link around the image disappeared.

Here is a little snippet of my layout
[4x4 Grid snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knnhs.png)
Here is the code for one of the blocks

```css
.new-hide-on-mobile {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.new-hide-on-mobile:hover:after {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.2;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="new-hide-on-mobile">
<a href="https://www.somatechnology.com/AnesthesiaMachines.aspx"><img itemprop="image" src="https://somatechnology.com/images/images_for_home/Rollovers/anesthesia_machine_cat.jpg" alt="Anesthesia Machines offered by Soma Technology, Inc." width="152" height="152"></a><br></div>
```

I understand there is something going on with the content: ''; property but if I take that out it doesn't do the rollover effect I am looking for. Am I going about this all wrong? Should I be doing something else?

Comment: That's because the pseudo-element is covering the link, try using the pseudo element of `a`

Comment: If Internet Explorer is not a must, try the [Brightness Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter?v=example#brightness()_2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Brightness Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter?v=example#brightness()_2).
It's supported in all major browsers, except IE.

---

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://www.somatechnology.com/AnesthesiaMachines.aspx">
  <img itemprop="image" src="https://somatechnology.com/images/images_for_home/Rollovers/anesthesia_machine_cat.jpg" alt="Anesthesia Machines offered by Soma Technology, Inc." width="152" height="152">
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.1);
    filter: brightness(1.1);
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bof10v1m/1/).

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware of the brightness filter. Makes things a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the pseudo element of the div covers the link. You can use the pseudo element of the anchor so that you can have a clickable overlay.

```css
.new-hide-on-mobile {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.new-hide-on-mobile a:hover:after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.2;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="new-hide-on-mobile">
  <a href="https://www.somatechnology.com/AnesthesiaMachines.aspx"><img itemprop="image" src="https://somatechnology.com/images/images_for_home/Rollovers/anesthesia_machine_cat.jpg" alt="Anesthesia Machines offered by Soma Technology, Inc." width="152" height="152"></a>
  <br>
</div>
```